# admob mediation custom event Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks

Tags: ios, admob, custom-events

I followed the [custom event example](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/training/mediation/custom-events/banners) at developers.google.com, but failed to receive ad from the custom ad network with the error in title.

After I requesting the ad for custom event, `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` in class `CustomAd` did get called. But then (a few seconds later), it jumped to `adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` with following error. And my custom network ad request in `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` did not work.

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks." UserInfo=0x1e8e31a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks.}

I tries to add `[self.delegate customEventBanner:self didReceiveAd:bannerView_];` to `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:`, and then it works.

My question is:

Am I doing it right? Should I call `[self.delegate customEventBanner:self didReceiveAd:bannerView_];` manually from `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:`, which is not mentioned in the official doc.

And for the custom event ad request which trigger the `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` later, should I set `gadBannerView_.delegate` for it. When I set it, and later successfully receive custom event (`requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` get called), why the `adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError` get called but not the `adViewDidReceiveAd:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to call `[self.delegate customEventBanner:self didReceiveAd:bannerView_];` at some point in your custom event flow. If you don't do so within about 5 seconds of `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` being invoked, AdMob Mediation will time out on the request to your custom event and move on. That's why you're seeing the message:

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks." UserInfo=0x1e8e31a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks.}

As far as when to invoke `[self.delegate customEventBanner:self didReceiveAd:bannerView_];`, it depends on your custom event. If your custom event just returns a static image, you can invoke `didReceiveAd:` directly in `requestBannerAd:parameter:label:request:` with that image.

But if you're implementing some ad network that AdMob Mediation doesn't already support, chances are they will have some kind of listener to tell you when they received an ad (in AdMob's case, that would be `GADBannerViewDelegate`'s `adViewDidReceiveAd` callback). You should listen for that network's received ad callback and in that listener invoke `didReceiveAd:`.

For your main `GADRequest` to AdMob that ends up triggering your custom event, you should set a `GADBannerViewDelegate` on your `GADBannerView` to listen for the callbacks from your custom event or any other network you may have in your mediation flow. If you get `adViewDidReceiveAd:`, you know AdMob Mediation found an ad from one of your networks.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same issue in Xamarin.iOS but now I have resolved it :

[follow this step][for Xamarin.iOS]
`I. here I am passing a request for ads mob :

```
  adView.LoadRequest(request);
```

II. if adview has been failed on loading ads request.

```
 adView.ReceiveAdFailed += (object sender, BannerViewErrorEventArgs ea) => {
                                        viewOnScreen = false;
                    Console.WriteLine(ea.Error.Description);
                    adView.LoadRequest(request);
                                    };
```

III. then we will get mob ads response here.

```
 adView.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    viewOnScreen = true;
                    if (!viewOnScreen) this.AddSubview(adView);
                };`
```